# $("html").mask is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, mask

I tried to show the loading image by masking whole page. So other element in page is not accessible. But it's not working in IE7 only. In other browsers, it's working fine.

My code is

```
$('html').mask('<div class="loading-msg-wrapper"><div class="loading-icon"><img src="ajax-loader-tr.gif"></div><div class="loading-text">Loading ...</div></div>');
```

Css:

```
.loadmask {
    z-index: 6000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
}
.loadmask-msg {
    z-index: 60001;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border:1px solid #E80060;
    background: #E80060;
    padding:2px;
}
.loadmask-msg div.loading-outer-wrapper {
    padding:5px 10px 5px 25px;
    background: #fbfbfb url('../images/loading.gif') no-repeat 5px 5px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border:1px solid #E80060;
    color:#222;
    font:normal 11px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:wait;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and IE7 doesn't seem to like having things done directly to the html tag. Try using mask on $('body').

Comment: It may be by design, but setting it on the body selector should also work in all browsers, so that should be a good enough fix for now.